# Abstract class concrete method invokation

Tags: java

I have an abstract class called Animal. it has a concrete method called sleeping(). Then i have written another class called WildAnimal by extends Animals class. That overrides the sleeping() of abstract Animal class

I want to call abstract class concrete method into my main method (Not overridden method of WildAnimal class). I know that Abstract class can't be instantiated but is it possible to invoke abstract class concrete method() ? if Yes, How ?

Check this below code:

Animal Class (abstract):

```
 abstract class Animal {

   public void sleeping(){              
    System.out.println("Animal Sleeping...!");
   }
 }
```

WildAnimal class:

```
 class WildAnimal extends Animal{

    public void sleeping(){
       System.out.println("WildAnimal Sleeping...!");
    }
  }
```

AbsMethodTest (Test class):

```
 public class AbsMethodTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal ani = new WildAnimal();  // This will print "WildAnimal Sleeping...!"                    
    ani.sleeping();  // But i want to print "Animal Sleeping...!" is it possible ?
   }
 }
```

Comment: You have to use `super.sleeping()` in the overridden method. There is no other way.

Comment: Your questions results of Java's poorly elaborated inheritance mechanisms - it is a good OO practice, to have only three types of methods in abstract classes: Final, empty or abstract.

Comment: It is how polymorphism in Java works. Take a look at [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). For solution take a look at Rohit comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, unless you have an `Animal` implementation that does not override `sleeping()`. As far as the client code is concerned, it shouldn't "know" who provides the behavior of the `sleeping` method. From its point of view, it simply calls the `sleeping` behavior of the `WildAnimal` specialization. It cannot "want" the superclass implementation to be called, because it simply should not "know" that the behavior it calls is specific to the subclass or inherited from the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You must do:

```
class WildAnimal extends Animal{

public void sleeping(){
    // System.out.println("WildAnimal Sleeping...");
    super.sleeping();
    }
}
```